# Python exception: error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, prediction

I have recently installed predictionio for recommendations on vagrant box. I'm fairly new to it. When I try to run its python sample file import_eventserver, I run into the following error:

```
C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\PredictionIO-Vagrant-0.8.2\MyRecommendation>python data/imp
ort_eventserver.py --access_key some_access_key
Namespace(access_key='some_access_key', file='./data/sample_movielens_data.txt', url='http://localhost:7070')
```

Importing data...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data/import_eventserver.py", line 76, in <module>
    import_events(client, args.file)
  File "data/import_eventserver.py", line 45, in import_events
    target_entity_id=data[1]
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\predictionio-0.8.3-py2.7.egg\predictionio\
__init__.py", line 243, in create_event
    event_time).get_response()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\predictionio-0.8.3-py2.7.egg\predictionio\
connection.py", line 113, in get_response
    self._response = self.rfunc(tmp_response)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\predictionio-0.8.3-py2.7.egg\predictionio\
__init__.py", line 120, in _acreate_resp
    (response.error, response.request))
predictionio.NotCreatedError: Exception happened: [Errno 10054] An existing conn
ection was forcibly closed by the remote host for request POST /events.json?acce
ssKey=some_access_key {'eventTime': '2015-01-26T02:16:36.285+0000', 'entityType': 'user', 'targetEntityType': '
item', 'targetEntityId': '2', 'entityId': '0', 'event': 'buy'} /events.json?acce
ssKey=enFymhjuV3ighOz9R3u3FuiWSHNgWch241WbaTaXpdXyNJbKp5tYWO5IplkxUvR7?eventTime
=2015-01-26T02%3A16%3A36.285%2B0000&entityType=user&targetEntityType=item&target
EntityId=2&entityId=0&event=buy
```

Any ideas on how to know whats wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that the below commands are required to solve this error. When you run PIO eventserver or deploy engine inside the VM, you need to specify "--ip 0.0.0.0" in order to access the event server and deployed engine from the host machine:

To run eventserver:
$ pio eventserver --ip 0.0.0.0

To deploy engine:
$  pio deploy --ip 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with the Prediction IO API. The error message you get  shows a connection is drawn from the connection pool and the connection to the server has been lost.
Is the error reproducible ? Arent' you getting network issues ? Pls check network connectivity between components. 
I just tried and installed w/ Python, on a Mac w/ Vagrant , and everything worked fine for me..